# Is it possible to get a diff-view of other users edits?

Tags: support, edits, diff

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764261/how-to-convert-to-a-gst-date) had a lot of grammar and spelling errors, also broken code etc., so I fixed what I could.

My edit got accepted directly by "Community" and got a second "edit" from another user. I am fine with that, as there were so many errors in the original question that I might have overlooked several issues.

When my edit was pending approval, I got to see [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10877970) where the original and my changes were side-by-side. [I have found out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work), that this is called "revisions", but I can't see the revision page with the latest version of the last user that has edited the question.

So am I missing the button/link to get to the revision-site or is this a feature for people with more than a specific reputation?

I would like to see the differences and understand what I have overlooked or could have done better while editing.

Comment: I have found the URL that links to the revisions and manually put the ID for the question into that: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34764261/revisions ... now I see the revisions, but still dont have a clue how to get to the page. Also means, that I have the rights to view the revisions.

Comment: Click the line of text above the user who edited the question ("edited ..... ago") http://i.imgur.com/nmpWkyt.png

Comment: Ah! No wonder my `CTRL+F` for `revision` did not find anything in Firefox... thank you! But I have to add, that this is very hidden and not intuitive. At least not for me. :/

Comment: @Thaillie write an answer please with that screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Thallie](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314609/is-it-possible-to-get-a-diff-view-of-other-users-edits#comment293829_314609) mentions, you can click the line of text (*edited ... mins ago*) above the user who edited the question.

[image]